# How do I access cocoa pods library and add a module to it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am using macincloud to do some xcode work and I have a xcode package that works fine on the computer it was made on, but in macincloud I get a no module error. How do I check on my pod library, is it part of the of the computer or is part of my code?

I have read about opening up terminal and typing in different commands to install pods but nothing is working

Here is what is in my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'WallpaperBoard' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    pod 'DBImageColorPicker'
    pod 'SSUIViewMiniMe'
  # Pods for WallpaperBoard

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoapods is a dependency manager. Running the `pod install` command on Terminal, it downloads all the Pods as external dependencies and creates a `.xcworkspace` for your project.

It needs to be run once in every different computer you run your project.

On Mac In Cloud:

1. Open Terminal
2. Navigate to the project folder, where the Podfile is. Usually you can navigate with the `cd` command. Example:

```
cd  /Users/user_name/Desktop/project_folder
```

3. Run the command to install the Pods:

```
pod install
```

4. Open the generated `.xcworkspace` file

Comment: I just did this and it looks like all my pod file are now installed which is great. Does it matter if you open from the .xcworkspace file or the .xcodeproj file? I have always been opening from the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: You need to open the .xcworkspace from now on. The .xcodeproj file alone doesn’t have access to the installed pods

Comment: Thank you, I just did that and ran build and even though it stated some errors it said the build was successful.